# Socket.io namespace gives Cannot GET error using Node.js on localhost

Tags: node.js, socket.io, namespaces, portforwarding

I am trying to set up a game server using socket.io and express on Node.js. I thought I followed the socket.io documentation on namespaces correctly but when I run the following code and visit http://localhost:129/host, I get a 404 - "cannot GET /host" error.

My router doesn't allow Dynamic DNS so I have to use the IP with the port and I can't find any documentation that explains how to reference that with a namespace. If I only navigate to http://localhost:129 the page loads and the server-side messages show up in the console but not the client-side ones. Thanks in advance.

Server-side (index.js)

```
var express = require('express');  

var app = express(); 
var server = require('http').createServer(app).listen(process.env.PORT || 129);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
const host = io.of("/host");
const game = io.of("/game");
const player = io.of("/player");

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));  
app.get('/', function(req, res,next) {  
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

player.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('Player connected...');
});

host.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('Host connected...');
});
    
game.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('Game connected...');
});
```

Client-side (index.html)

```
<!doctype html>  
<html lang="en">  
    <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="player">
            <h1>Welcome!</h1><p>There's nothing to play yet. Come back here when the games begin!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="game">
        </div>
        <div id="host">
        </div>
        
        <script src="/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script> 
            var name = '';
            var player = io('/player');
            var host = io('/host');
            var game = io('/game');
            
            player.on('connect', function(data) {
                console.log('Player client connected');
            });
            host.on('connect', function(data) {
                console.log('Host client connected');
            });
            game.on('connect', function(data) {
                console.log('Game client connected');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

DEBUG OUTPUT

```
express:application set "x-powered-by" to true +0ms
  express:application set "etag" to 'weak' +3ms
  express:application set "etag fn" to [Function: generateETag] +1ms
  express:application set "env" to 'development' +2ms
  express:application set "query parser" to 'extended' +1ms
  express:application set "query parser fn" to [Function: parseExtendedQueryString] +1ms
  express:application set "subdomain offset" to 2 +1ms
  express:application set "trust proxy" to false +1ms
  express:application set "trust proxy fn" to [Function: trustNone] +1ms
  express:application booting in development mode +0ms
  express:application set "view" to [Function: View] +1ms
  express:application set "views" to 'C:\\server\\views' +1ms
  express:application set "jsonp callback name" to 'callback' +1ms
  socket.io:server initializing namespace / +0ms
  socket.io:server creating engine.io instance with opts {"path":"/socket.io"} +4ms
  socket.io:server attaching client serving req handler +29ms
  socket.io:server initializing namespace /host +1ms
  socket.io:server initializing namespace /game +0ms
  express:router use '/' query +133ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +1ms
  express:router use '/' expressInit +2ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +1ms
  express:router use '/' serveStatic +2ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +1ms
  express:router:route new '/' +1ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +0ms
  express:router:route get '/' +2ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +1ms
```

Comment: You need to look in the browser console and see what errors you're seeing there.

Comment: It only says 404 not found

Comment: What is the entire error message?  What EXACT URL is not found?

Comment: `GET http://localhost:129/host 404 (Not Found)________________________:129/host:1`

Comment: I can't explain it.  When I do `io("/host")`, my browser does NOT attempt a connection to `/host`.  It attempts a connection to `/socket.io` (which is the usual socket.io URL for a new connection) and once the connection is established, then it sends a socket.io message that it wants to connect on the `/host` namespace.  So, something is apparently not configured or loaded correctly in your client.